# embed string with flash object not showing

Tags: flash, cross-browser, embed

so I have something weird going on. This is my code

```
$j(".openWin").click(function(){
        var flashObj ='‹object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="movie_name" align="middle">;          
                //$j("#embedInHere").append(flashObj);
                var win = window.open('','',"width=600, height=600");
                win.focus();

                $j(win.document).find('body').append(flashObj);

            });
```

Basically what I'm doing is creating a string with a flash object and embedding into a new window. Now this works perfectly with IE9 and Firefox but for Chrome and Safari I have to resize the new window and then the flash object appears.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bug.
You should really use SWFObject to embed your flash object anyway as this is more browser compliant.

Comment: Ok I'll try using SWFObject and see if that helps.